# How to get white space or nil object from cucumber table?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gherkin

I try to pass white space character in my test.

So I try the following in my cucumber step

```
If I enter:
|company_name|phone|
||#{nil}|
```

I get `{"company_name"=>"", "phone"=>"\#{nil}"}`

```
|company_name|phone|
| | |
```

I get `{"company_name"=>"", "phone"=>""}`

```
|company_name|phone|
|\s|\nil|
```

I get `{"company_name"=>"\\s", "phone"=>"\nil"}`

```
|company_name|phone|
|" "|' '|
```

I get `{"company_name"=>"\" \"", "phone"=>"' '"}`

What I should put in the table to get the following hash `{"company_name"=>" ", "phone"=>" "}` ?

Comment: give us the code you are using.

Comment: No code needed here.
I just need to pass such string => " " or nil object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no value you can put in a cucumber table that is interpreted as `nil` by default. You can use a [cucumber Transform](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Argument-Transforms) to do what you want. For example, you could use it like this if you wanted to interpret an empty string as `nil`:

```
Transform /^table:company_name,phone$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.map! do |h|
    h.each_pair do |k,v|
      h[k] = nil if v == '' #here, you can map any value you want to be nil
    end
  end

  table
end
```

Put this in a file in your support folder. There are also other methods like `map_column!` etc you can use if you want to transform just one column.

Comment: Ok! It's clear now, how to pass nil object.
But, for example, in the "company_address" I need to pass both ```""``` or ```" "```. How do I do that?

Comment: @mef_ you can transform only certain keys by using either `map_column!` for the ones you want to transform or by adding a second condition regarding keys to the code above. (For example, something like: `h[k] = nil if v == '' and %W(company_name phone).include?(k)` to map only the company name and the phone to nil if empty. If you want to map other values to `nil`, add other conditions to the expression likewise.

Comment: Thanks! Transform method helps me.
I case where I want to put ```" "``` I use transform method like this ```h[k] = " " if v == 's'```
Thus in my table I pass ```'s'``` string